Filament Form Fieldset or Repeater Not Displaying Full-Width Properly in Laravel Filament Form
I am working on a Laravel project using Filament to build a form, and I'm having issues with the layout of a Repeater within a Section. Despite setting columns(4) and explicitly defining column spans for each field, the fields do not display in a row or take up the full width of the page.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
\Filament\Forms\Components\Section::make()
    ->heading('اطلاعات شغلی')
    ->columns(4) // Section uses a 4-column grid
    ->schema([
        Repeater::make('interests')
            ->relationship('interests')
            ->label('علاقه‌مندی‌ها')
            ->schema([
                Select::make('interest_id')
                    ->label('نوع اشتغال')
                    ->options(Interest::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray())
                    ->required()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->columnSpan(2),

                Select::make('state_id')
                    ->label('استان محل اشتغال')
                    ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn(string $search): array => State::query()
                        ->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->limit(10)
                        ->pluck('name', 'id')
                        ->toArray())
                    ->getOptionLabelUsing(fn($value): ?string => State::find($value)?->name)
                    ->required()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->columnSpan(1),

                Select::make('city_id')
                    ->label('شهر محل اشتغال')
                    ->required()
                    ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn(string $search, Get $get): array => City::query()
                        ->whereRelation('state', 'id', '=', $get('state_id'))
                        ->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->limit(10)
                        ->pluck('name', 'id')
                        ->toArray())
                    ->getOptionLabelUsing(fn($value): ?string => City::find($value)?->name)
                    ->placeholder('انتخاب کنید')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->visible(fn(Get $get) => !empty($get('state_id')))
                    ->columnSpan(1),

                Select::make('university_id')
                    ->label('دانشگاه محل فعالیت فعلی')
                    ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn(string $search, Get $get): array => University::query()
                        ->whereRelation('state', 'id', '=', $get('state_id'))
                        ->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->limit(10)
                        ->pluck('name', 'id')
                        ->toArray())
                    ->getOptionLabelUsing(fn($value): ?string => University::find($value)?->name)
                    ->placeholder('انتخاب کنید')
                    ->required()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->columnSpan(2),

                TextInput::make('activity_place')
                    ->label('محل فعالیت')
                    ->nullable()
                    ->columnSpan(4), // Full row
            ])
            ->columns(4) // Repeater uses a 4-column grid
            ->label('اطلاعات شغلی')
            ->required(),
    ]),

But now the problem is:
Fields within the Repeater are not displayed in a proper row or full-width layout.
Even though I’ve set columns(4) for both the Section and the Repeater, the form elements seem to be confined to a narrower width than expected.
The columnSpan for each field (e.g., columnSpan(2) or columnSpan(4)) doesn't seem to affect the layout as expected.
Result:

What I tried:

Explicitly setting columns() on both the Section and the Repeater.
Adjusting the columnSpan values to ensure fields align properly.

Expected Behavior:
The fields within the Repeater should:

Display properly in rows according to the columnSpan values.

Occupy the full width of the page, respecting the 4-column grid
layout.


So, How can I ensure that the Repeater fields within the Section, Use the full page width?
Is there something I’m missing in the configuration, or could this be related to Filament's CSS/JS?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.
Laravel: 10.x
Filament: 3.x
PHP: 8.1

AFAIK, Filament's grid system relies on parent container's config(columns() on Repeater & Section)... If Repeater's grid does not match its parent, fields can become misaligned or behave unexpectedly. Also If Section component doesn't span full width, the child grid (Repeater) will also be constrained. So you're doing it wrong

The repeater column span is 1 by default, so it is filling a single column, which is why it's all squished.
For the repeater to span the full width:

use ->colSpanFull() on the repeater (or ->colSpan(4))
remove ->columns(4) from the section (or change to ->columns(1))


